# RunTime Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA for excel and I am stuck with a little problem. I have a list of data and I have two task I want to complete.

The first will delete rows with any values in the J column that is equal to 0;

The second part: I want to loop through the rows left over and delete any rows that the value in I column is greater than the value In J column.

However I'm getting the following error: VBA RunTime Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

This is on the line that states:

```
For rw = .Cells(rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
```

The full code is

```
Private Sub clearupdata_Click()

Dim rows As Range, OSQty As Range, value As Long, rw As Long

Set OSQty = Range("j2")

Do Until OSQty.value = ""
    value = Val(OSQty.value)
    If (value = 0) Then
        If rows Is Nothing Then
            Set rows = OSQty.EntireRow
        Else
            Set rows = Union(OSQty.EntireRow, rows)
        End If
    End If
    Set OSQty = OSQty.Offset(1)
Loop

If Not rows Is Nothing Then rows.Delete

With Worksheets(1)   '<~~ worksheet ~~>
    For rw = .Cells(rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
         If .Cells(rw, "I").Value2 > .Cells(rw, "J").Value2 Then
             .rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
         End If
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Using `rows` as a variable name for a Range object is not a good idea because there is already a `Rows` property defined on the Application, Worksheet and Range objects

Comment: as barrowc said, rows.count might think its the range variable named  rows.  i tried rename the range it works

Answer (score 1):

just change:

```
For rw = .Cells(rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
```

to

```
For rw = .Cells(.rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
```

the difference is when you call the function from a different sheet the `rows.count` is not for the same sheet so it falls over.

Comment: Solution is ok, but explanation should be slightly different. It has nothing to do with different sheet, `rows.count` without dot will never work, since `.Rows` is a method of class `Sheet` and always must be preceded with an object of this class.

Comment: fair enough. I actually thought if sheet in this kind of a case is not specified it takes `activesheet` by default and I assumed it will run ok, which I just checked it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rows2 As Range
```

won't compromise later with `.Cells(.rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row`,

because `rows.count` would trigger the error, +1 to barrowc